# Hibernate doesn't see tables with quotes in name

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have some tables in db(postgresql) with names like this `"Test"`.When i try create java classes from this tables with hibernate its not happening. I get classes from tables with names like this `test`. How to make hibernate can see tables with quotes in names?

**UPDATE**

Maybe i write question not correct. But i cant create java classes and i want to know how to do reverse ingenering with tables which have names in qoutes. I cant delete qoutes from table names and column names couse they have names like Type and Full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Hibernate assumes the database table name is the same as the class name, but you can override this behaviour via the `@Table` annotation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"Test\"") // Will use "Test" (including the quotes) as the table name
public class Test {
```

Comment: In which file i gonna do this?

Answer (score 0):

The @Table annotation is used to specify the table to persist the data. The name attribute refers to the table name. If @Table annotation is not specified then Hibernate will by default use the class name as the table name. So your database's table name is "Test" then you should use your class name is "Test".

Comment: Is it possible to have Class Named as `"Test"`?

Comment: @BharatSinha No: Class names must start with a letter

Comment: Arr give database table name "test", and use entity name "Test" with @Table(name="test").

Comment: Maybe i write question not correct. But i cant create java classes and i want to know how to do reverse ingenering with tables which have names in qoutes. I cant delete qoutes from table names and column names couse they have names like `Type` and `Full`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your database with
`select * from """Test"""` if your table name is "Test".

Your entity class should be

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"\"\"Test\"\"\"")
public class Test {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not using annotations as of now...

So in case you want to use `"Test"` as table name you should define the mapping of POJO with your table either via annotations as defined by Bohemian

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"Test\"")
public class Test {
```

or define in the `Test.hbm.xml` in which you have to map your table and fields to java class and columns.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you can specify the schema and database name inside @Table annotation.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Test", schema = "public", catalog = "TestDatabase")
```

Hibernate will recognize the table without the need to escape double quotes.